# (Excel VBA) Inserting Check Boxes (OKAY) & Linking Them To Cells In A Separate Sheet (Not OKAY)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a short macro to insert check boxes into cells in a sheet called "Dashboard" and which works fine, but I need to link them to cells in a different sheet (in the same workbook), which I call "Range" and has all sorts of True/False and list populations.

There will be something like 1000 checkboxes when this is all over.  I am aware of how cumbersome they are.  The linked cells should be in the exact same location, but in the "Range" sheet.

Currently, it will link to cells in the same sheet using offset, but I'm unsure how to interpret the .LinkedCell property to link instead to another sheet.

I've fumbled a bit with assigning them to the "range" sheet, with no success because of the .Name property.

My expected results are to create a mirror image of "Dashboard" within "Range" that represents the linked cells.

```
Dim c As Range
Dim myCBX As CheckBox
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rngCB As Range
Dim strCAP As String

Set wks = ActiveSheet
Set rngCB = wks.Range("C2:D4") 'This range will be 130 rows and 10 or more columns when I'm finished.

strCAP = ""

For Each c In rngCB
    With c
        Set myCBX = wks.CheckBoxes.Add(Top:=c.Top - 2, Width:=3, Height:=c.Height, Left:=c.Left + c.Width * 0.425)
        'Set myCBX = wks.CheckBoxes.Add(Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
    End With

    With myCBX

        'This is where it links the checkbox to a cell in the same sheet.
        'I'm unsure how to interpret .Name and LinkedCell to assign them to a sheet called "Range"
        .Name = "cbx_' & c.Address(0,0)"

        .LinkedCell = c.Offset(0, 2).Address(external:=True) 'This offset is specific to the amount of intended end-use columns.

        .Caption = strCAP


        End With
    Next c
```

Comment: Try to something like `LinkedCell = "'Sheet2'!" & c.Address`. Also may change  `Name = "cbx_' & c.Address(0,0)"  to  `Name = "cbx_" & c.Address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own question, and thought I'd share it.

I found this separate function online and ran it after I ran the original one, which successfully placed 1200 or so check boxes.  However, the boxes slowed down excel so much that I changed it to an array of 1's and 0's which then linked to the True/False table in the range tab, so that everything else still functioned.

```
Sub ALinkCheckBoxes()
   Dim chk As CheckBox

   For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    'There is a random amount experimental of offsetting which visually aligned it within the center of the cell.
      chk.LinkedCell = "Range!" & chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(-9, 6).Address
   Next chk

End Sub
```